# Simple calculator with rpcgen

Tags: c, linux, calculator

I am new in programming in C. I try to create a small and simple program to the addition of two integers from file calculs.x

Here, the contents of the file calculs.x

```
/* calculs.x*/

struct data_in {
    int arg1;
    int arg2;
};
typedef struct data_in data_in;

struct result_int {
    int result;
    int errno;
};

struct result_float {
    int result;
    int errno;
};

typedef struct result_int result_int;
typedef struct result_float result_float;

program CALCULS{
    version VERSION_UN{
        void CALCULS_NULL(void) = 0;
        result_int ADD (data_in) = 1;
        result_int SUB(data_in) = 2;
        result_int MUL(data_in) = 3;
        result_float DIV (data_in) = 4;
    } = 1;
} = 0x20000001;
```

For the first time, I created a file calculs.c for a client:

```
#include <rpc/rpc.h>
#include "calculs.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int buffer[256];
    struct data_in input;
    struct result_int *output;
    CLIENT *cl;

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("usage: client hostname_of_server\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*Etablir le lien vers le serveur distant
     * cl = clnt_create(server, PROG, VERS, prot);
     */
    cl = clnt_create(argv[1], CALCULS, VERSION_UN, "tcp");
    if (cl == NULL) {
        clnt_pcreateerror(argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    input.arg1 = 5;
    input.arg2 = 5;

    output = add_1(&input, cl);
    if (output == NULL) {
        clnt_perror(cl, argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("the result field is %d\n", output->result);
    printf("the errno field is %d\n", output->errno);

    clnt_destroy(cl);

    return 0;
}
```

I have not received any error compiling for this file, but for another rcalculs.c file, I can not compile. Here is the file contents rcalculs.c:

```
#include <rpc/rpc.h>
#include "calculs.h"

result_int *add_1(struct data_in data, struct svc_req *rqstp) {
    int buffer;
    struct result_int result;
    int a = data.arg1;
    int b = data.arg2;
    buffer = a+b;
    result.result = buffer;
    result.errno =0;
    return result;
}
```

The message error for compiling is

```
rcalculs.c:11:13: erreur: conflicting types for ‘add_1’
In file included from rcalculs.c:9:0:
calculs.h:46:22: note: previous declaration of ‘add_1’ was here
rcalculs.c: In function ‘add_1’:
rcalculs.c:19:5: erreur: incompatible types when returning type ‘struct result_int’ but ‘struct result_int *’ was expected
```

could you help me to resolve this problem, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
erreur: conflicting types for ‘add_1
```

This error is because You did not declare add_1() function. and when ever you made function call to add_1() it treats as declaration.

Add this line before `main()`

```
  result_int *add_1(struct data_in data, struct svc_req *rqstp);
```

---

rcalculs.c:19:5: erreur: incompatible types when returning type ‘struct result_int’ but ‘struct result_int *’ was expected

```
  result_int * add_1(struct data_in data, struct svc_req *rqstp) {
    int buffer;
    struct result_int result; //here declare pointer
    int a = data.arg1;
    int b = data.arg2;
    buffer = a+b;
    result.result = buffer; //change here
    result.errno =0;        //change here 
    return result; //here you are returning struct result_int type but required is struct result_int * type 
   }
```

return pointer. And do changes accordingly in your function.

---

```
output = add_1(&input, cl); //here you are passing reference of input but you just need to pass input.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use your calculs.x in tact as below.

```
/* calculs.x*/

struct data_in {
    int arg1;
    int arg2;
};
typedef struct data_in data_in;

struct result_int {
    int result;
    int errno;
};

struct result_float {
    int result;
    int errno;
};

typedef struct result_int result_int;
typedef struct result_float result_float;

program CALCULS{
    version VERSION_UN{
        void CALCULS_NULL(void) = 0;
        result_int ADD (data_in) = 1;
        result_int SUB(data_in) = 2;
        result_int MUL(data_in) = 3;
        result_float DIV (data_in) = 4;
    } = 1;
} = 0x20000001;
```

For your client calculs.c user

```
#include <rpc/rpc.h>
#include "calculs.h"

result_int *add_1(struct data_in data, struct svc_req *rqstp);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int buffer[256];
    struct data_in input;
    struct result_int *output;
    CLIENT *cl;

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("usage: client hostname_of_server\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*Etablir le lien vers le serveur distant
     * cl = clnt_create(server, PROG, VERS, prot);
     */
    cl = clnt_create(argv[1], CALCULS, VERSION_UN, "tcp");
    if (cl == NULL) {
        clnt_pcreateerror(argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    input.arg1 = 5;
    input.arg2 = 5;

    output = add_1(&input, cl);
    if (output == NULL) {
        clnt_perror(cl, argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("the result field is %d\n", output->result);
    printf("the errno field is %d\n", output->errno);

    clnt_destroy(cl);

    return 0;
}
```

contents of rcalculs.c:

```
#include <rpc/rpc.h>
#include "calculs.h"

result_int *add_1(struct data_in data, struct svc_req *rqstp) {
    int buffer;
    struct result_int result;
    int a = data.arg1;
    int b = data.arg2;
    buffer = a+b;
    result.result = buffer;
    result.errno =0;
    return &result;
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the function `add_1` as returning a pointer to a `result_int` when you say

```
result_int *add_1(struct data_in data, struct svc_req *rqstp) {
```

in your file `rcalculs.c`

However, inside that function you define

```
struct result_int result;
```

and when you return a value, you do

```
return result;
```

If you don't want an error, you would have to do

```
return &result;
```

The problem with that is that your `result` variable was created locally inside the function (on the stack) - so that it will become invalid once the function returns. A quick and ugly "fix" for this would be to define your variable as `static` (meaning that 1- it will continue to exist after the function returns, but 2- your function is no longer thread safe: if it gets called from two different places there is no knowing what value will be referenced).

You did not post your `.h` file so I am guessing a little bit, but I think the following change to `rcalculs.c`  would "fix" your problem (but note the comment above... this is NOT considered good programming practice)

```
#include <rpc/rpc.h>
#include "calculs.h"

result_int *add_1(struct data_in data, struct svc_req *rqstp) {
    int buffer;
    static struct result_int result;
    int a = data.arg1;
    int b = data.arg2;
    buffer = a+b;
    result.result = buffer;
    result.errno =0;
    return &result;
}
```

Let me know if that works. Note - this is intended just to help you understand the error - I DO NOT RECOMMEND this as program structure for a "real" program.

Bonne chance!